# Parse all tags and tag content into an array?

Tags: php, parsing, hyperlink

I would like to be able to find all anchor tags in a string and parse them into an array like so:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="link1.php" title="title1">One</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://something.com/link2.php" title="title2">Two</a> Nunc augue nunc, ullamcorper at mattis';
```

Output to an array like this:
    array (
        0 => 
            array (
                'title' => 'title1',
                'href' => 'link1.php',
                'inner' => 'One',
            ),
        1 => 
            array (
                'title' => 'title2',
                'href' => 'http://something.com/link2.php',
                'inner' => 'Two',
            )
    )

Comment: What have you tried? Have you heard of `DOMDocument` class? What's the question again?

Comment: $links = array();
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(wp_nav_menu($defaults));
    $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
     $links[] = array(
      'title' => $tag->getAttribute('title'),
      'href' => $tag->getAttribute('href'),
     ); 
    }

Comment: Im not sure how to enter code properly.. I have tried the above, but i am unable to get the contents of the <a> tag @Forien

Comment: you could edit question instead of pasting code into comments. Anyway, inside `foreach`, your `$tag` is instance of `DOMNode` class. Which means you can `$tag->textContent` (it's property, not method!) to get text from within node.